# NOT(~) bitwise operator on signed type number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm having little trouble understanding how `not(~)` operator work for positive signed number.

as an example -ve numbers are stored in 2's compliment

```
int a=-5; 
cout<<bitset<32>(a)<<endl;  // 11111111111111111111111111111011
cout<<bitset<32>(~a)<<endl; // 00000000000000000000000000000100
cout<<(~a)<<endl; // 4
```

4 is an expected output

but

```
int a=5;
cout<<bitset<32>(a)<<endl;  // 00000000000000000000000000000101
cout<<bitset<32>(~a)<<endl; // 11111111111111111111111111111010
cout<<(~a)<<endl; // -6
```

how come -6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise not (`~`) operator can basically be summarized as the following

```
~x == -(x+1)
```

The reason for this is because negation (unary `-`) uses [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), in general.

Two's complement is defined as taking the bitwise not and then adding one i.e. `-x == (~x) + 1`. Simple transposition of the `+ 1` to the other side and then using distributive property of the negative sign (i.e. distributive property of multiplication, specifically with `-1` in this case), we get the equation on top.

In a more mathematical sense:

```
-x == (~x) + 1  // Due to way negative numbers are stored in memory (in 2's complement)
-x - 1 == ~x    // Transposing the 1 to the other side
-(x+1) == ~x    // Distributing the negative sign
```

Comment: how did you come to the approach of ~x == -(x+1) , can you prove it?

Comment: Note also that `~` is equivalent to [1's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) negation.

Comment: but int a=5 isn't -ve and cout<<bitset<32>(a); is giving 00000000000000000000000000000101 like just another unsigned number. Would it be wrong to say that only -ve numbers are stored in 2's compliment?

Comment: @JerryGoyal: whether a signed number is negative or not is decided by its MSB (most significant bit). if it is 1, then the number is understood as is, otherwise, it is understood to be in the 2's complement...

Comment: if int a= 5 and int a = -5, will both be stored in 2's complement or only latter one? because cout<<bitset<32>(a) is giving different bits in both.

Comment: Only latter. 2's complement is only used for negative numbers, though using a `signed int` means that what i mentioned above (regarding MSB) is applied to understand what is in memory.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard only says that the binary NOT operator (~) flips all the bits that are used to represent the value. What this means for the integer value depends on what interpretation of the bits your machine uses. The C++ standard allows the following three representations of signed integers:

- sign+magnitde: There is a sign bit followed by bits encoding the magnitude.
- one's complement: The idea is to represent -x by flipping all bits of x. This is similar to sign+magnitude where in the negative cases the magnitude bits are all flipped. So, 1...1111 would be -0, 1...1110 would be -1, 1...1101 would be -2 and so on...
- [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement): This representation removes one of two possible encodings for zero and adds a new value at the lower end. In two's complement 1...1111 represents -1, 1...1110 represents -2 and so on. So, it's basically one shifted down compared to one's complement.

Two's complement is *much* more popular these days. X86, X64, ARM, MIPS all use this representation for signed numbers as far as I know. Your machine apparently also uses two's complement because you observed ~5 to be -6.

If you want to stay 100% portable you should not rely on the two's complement representation and only use these kinds of operators on unsigned types.

Comment: as you said NOT operator (~) flips all the bits so for case of 5: 00000000000000000000000000000101 is fliped to 11111111111111111111111111111010 but why its value showing as -6? that's my main concern

Answer (score 0):

It is due to how the computer understands signed numbers.
take a byte : 8 bits.

1 (the strong one) for de sign

7 for the number
as a whole :
so from -128 to +127

for negative numbers :
-128 to -1

for positive numbers : 0 to 127.

there is no need to have two 0 in numbers, therefore, there is one more negative number.